# Check if an object (with certain properties values) not in list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new in Python. I am using Python v2.7.

I have defined a simple class `Product`:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, price, height, width):
        self.price = price
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
```

Then, I created a list, which is then appended with a `Product` object:

```
# empty list
prod_list = []
# append a product to the list, all properties have value 3
prod1 = Product(3,3,3)
prod_list.append(prod1)
```

Then, I created another `Product` object which is set the same initialize values (all 3):

```
prod2 = Product(3,3,3)
```

Then, I want to check if `prod_list` **doesn't** contain a `Product` object that has price=3, width=3 & height=3, by:

```
if prod2 not in prod_list:
   print("no product in list has price=3, width=3 & height=3")
```

I expect there is no print out message, but it is printed out. In Python, how can I check if a list doesn't have an object with certain property values then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add an `equality` attribute to your object. For getting the objects attributes you can pass the attribute names to `operator.attrgetter` which returns a tuple of gotten attributes then you can compare the tuples. Also you can use `__dict__` attribute which will gives you the module’s namespace as a dictionary object. Then you can get the attributes names which you want to compare the objects based on them.

```
from operator import attrgetter

class Product:
    def __init__(self, price, height, width):
        self.price = price
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def __eq__(self, val):
        attrs = ('width', 'price', 'height')
        return attrgetter(*attrs)(self) == attrgetter(*attrs)(val)

    def __ne__(self, val):
        attrs = ('width', 'price', 'height')
        return attrgetter(*attrs)(self) != attrgetter(*attrs)(val)
```

Edit:

As @Ashwini mentioned in comment based on python wiki:

> There are no implied relationships among the comparison operators. The
>   truth of `x==y` does not imply that `x!=y` is false. Accordingly, when
>   defining `__eq__()`, one should also define `__ne__()` so that the
>   operators will behave as expected.

So as a more comprehensive way I also added the `__ne__` attribute to the object. Which will return True if one of the attributes is not equal to it's relative one in other object.

Demo:

```
prod_list = []
prod1 = Product(3, 3, 3)
prod_list.append(prod1)

prod2 = Product(3, 3, 2)
prod_list.append(prod2)

prod3 = Product(3, 3, 3)
print prod3 in prod_list
True 
prod3 = Product(3, 3, 5)
print prod3 in prod_list
False
```

Comment: **Note**: [The truth of `x==y` does not imply that `x!=y` is false. Accordingly, when defining `__eq__()`, one should also define `__ne__()` so that the operators will behave as expected.](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, thanks for the great comment, but could you please show me how to define `__ne__()` ? I have no idea about it though I have read your link.

Comment: @Kasramvd , thanks! Though I have accpeted your answer, but could you please also explain a bit what does the `__ne__()` part code do?

Comment: @Leem.fin Welcome, just added.

Comment: @Kasramvd , thanks!  Looks like there is a typo in `__ne__()` code, you missed the `.` between `attrs` and `getter` , besides you should change `attr` to `attrs`

Comment: @Leem.fin No it's a function that has been imported from `operator` module.

Comment: We can also use `return not type(self).__eq__(self, val)` to make `x == y` equivalent of `not x != y`. Another advantage of this is that the logic then remains at only one place, for example if we later plan to remove one of the field from comparison then we need to update it at only one place.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, do you mean use `return not type(self).__eq__(self, val) ` in `__ne__()` ?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary,  why you use a `type` object to compare with an `Product` object `val` ? I mean type() function return a type object, right?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yes, like this it would be more precise but this won't be useful if the logic of `disproportion` and `equation` is not the same. For example for each of them we want to relay on different attributes. ( Although it's not reasonable but is possible)

Comment: @Leem.fin `type(self)` in this case is `Product` class.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, yes, I know that type(self) in this case is a Product class, but shouldn't we call `object.__eq__(another object)` ? Why you use Product `Class.__eq__(object)`? I lost on this. Do you mean `__eq__` is a class method?

Comment: @Leem.fin Because we want to use Product's `__eq__` method not `object`'s. `object.__eq__` will simply compare the identity. We can use `self.__eq__` as well but I prefer calling it on the class instead because one can easily define an attribute by the same on instance.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, thank you for your clarification, I just want to make sure I understand you correctly, do you mean `type(self).__eq__(self, val)` is invoking class level function `__eq__()`, with two parameters passed in i.e. `self` & `val`, and we are comparing these two in this class level function?

Comment: Great. That is very elegant in my case. Thanks! I will use this one for __ne__()